# Removing XML Tags with empty properties

Tags: sed, awk, xml

Input File:

```
<ServiceArea type="STATE" value="DC">
    <DaylightSavingsUsed value="true"/>
    <FemtoSipProxyAddress value="10.13.123.100"/>
    <TermAuthAAAPSK value="secret1"/>
    <PDSNDOParams index="1">
        <batchEndIpAddress value="68.28.121.68"/>
        <batchSecurityParameterIndex value="5262006"/>
        <batchStartIpAddress value="68.28.121.68"/>
    </PDSNDOParams>
    <PDSNDOParams index="2">
        <batchEndIpAddress value="68.28.113.68"/>
        <batchIOSVersion value="tia-878-a"/>
        <batchStartIpAddress value="68.28.113.68"/>
    </PDSNDOParams>
    <PDSN1XParams index="1">
        <batchEndIpAddress value="68.28.121.68"/>
        <batchSecretKey value="72563130317354663167345439615433"/>
        <batchSecurityParameterIndex value="5262006"/>
        <batchStartIpAddress value="68.28.121.68"/>
    </PDSN1XParams>
    <PDSN1XParams index="2">
        <batchEndIpAddress value="68.28.113.68"/>
        <batchIOSVersion value="tia-878-1"/>
    </PDSN1XParams>
</ServiceArea>

<ServiceArea type="ZIP" value="66221">
</ServiceArea>

<ServiceArea type="FIPS" value="46081">
    <DaylightSavingsUsed value="true"/>
    <MTA_Number value="22"/>
    <BC10_Utilization value="476,487,526"/>
</ServiceArea>

<ServiceArea type="FIPS" value="01824">
</ServiceArea>
```

I want to remove all the lines where there is no data between the

```
<ServiceArea type=
</ServiceArea>
```

In the above input I need to remove:

```
<ServiceArea type="ZIP" value="66221">
</ServiceArea>
```

and

```
<ServiceArea type="FIPS" value="01824">
</ServiceArea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xsltproc` for processing XML files by means of `xslt` scripts, aka style sheets. It would involve both an xslt script and a controlling bash script. For example:

**drompem.xslt**

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="ServiceArea">
    <xsl:if test="count(*)>0">
      <ServiceArea>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
      </ServiceArea>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**dropem.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<EOF | xsltproc dropem.xslt - | tail -n +2
<ALL>
$(cat)
</ALL>
EOF
```

The actual command would then be

```
./dropem.sh < infile > outfile
```

Notes: the `xslt` script includes a single "template" element that matches against your ServiceArea nodes, and conditionally (if it has children) copies it to the result.

The input needs to be wrapped into an enclosing tag pair because `xsltproc` only handles a single XML tree. The wrapping makes your data file into a single tree. The wrapping is not preserved for the output, which again is the list of ServiceArea sub trees.

However, the output is trimmed to avoid the `<?xml ...` preamble and blank line which `xsltproc` cannot avoid to emit.

The advantage with this approach is that its less sensitive to the input file line format. The disadvantage is that it uses `xslt`, which is a less common language.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `xmlstarlet` in different ways depending on how you want to detect the `ServiceArea` nodes:

- Delete all `ServiceArea` nodes that are "text nodes":

  ```bsh
  xmlstarlet ed -d '//ServiceArea[text()]' file.xml
  ```
- Delete all `ServiceArea` nodes that have zero child-nodes:

  ```bsh
  xmlstarlet ed -d '//ServiceArea[count(*)=0]' file.xml
  ```

Both of these depends on your document being well-formed.  Your example document isn't since it contains more than one root node.  Fixing this is a simple matter of adding e.g. `<root>` at the start and `</root>` at the end of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone will tell you to use proper xml-parsing tools to edit xml, but here's a simple awk script which assumes, as in your example, the ServiceArea tags are alone on separate lines:

```
awk '/<ServiceArea /{save = $0; next}
    save!="" {
       if(/<\/ServiceArea>/){ save = ""; next }
       print save
       save = ""
    }
    { print }'
```

This saves the line with the starting tag when it is seen. When the next line is read if we have a saved line but the current line is the ending tag then we suppress both. Otherwise print the saved line, then the current line.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I am getting the syntax error.  bash-3.2$ cat list | awk '/<ServiceArea /{save = $0; next}
>     save!="" {
>        if(/<\/ServiceArea>/){ save = ""; next }
>        print save
>        save = ""
>     }
>     { print }'
awk: syntax error near line 3
awk: illegal statement near line 3
awk: syntax error near line 4
awk: bailing out near line 4
bash-3.2$

Comment: what OS are you using? perhaps try `if($0~/<\/ServiceArea>/)` instead, or even `if($0~/<.ServiceArea>/)` to know what is the syntax error.

Comment: Its Solaris 10, The above command worked.... Thanks for helping

Comment: ok. Apparently on Solaris people suggest using `nawk` instead of `awk` to get similar functionality as on other platforms.